# missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun Failed to clone nvm repo

Tags: curl, terminal, nvm, xcrun

**

> curl -o-
>   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.0/install.sh |
>   bash

**

When I run this code on my Mac I got an error

> crun: error: invalid active developer path
>   (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at:
>   /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun Failed to clone nvm
>   repo. Please report this!

How to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed this problem by reinstalling Xcode.

Answer (score 67):

I solved this problem by opening the Terminal and running the command:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Answer (score 2):

Open xcode and goto preferences>Locations. Make sure Command Line Tools is installed.

This seems to have corrected my issue (described for others who get it). I have xcode installed and got a similar error when attempting to install a python3 lib psutil (python3 -m pip install psutil) on my Apple M1(mac silicon) Monterey:

> xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
>
> error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1